# Getting the indices of the top k numbers by value in a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Lets say there's a numpy array like the following:

```
import numpy as np
a = array([[1,2,3],[4,3,1]])
```

And you want to return the top 3 numbers. You can find the max by:

```
i,j = np.unravel_index(a.argmax(), a.shape)
```

But for the indices of the 2nd and 3rd top values, how can you find those? The only option I can think of is to set 0 for the value stored at the max index, and run the process again. There must be a better way right?

The answer for the following would be: (1,0), (0,2), (1,1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you pass the `axis=None` parameter to `argsort`, it returns the sorted indexes of the flattened array (in ascending order). The `numpy.unravel_index` function converts the indexes of a flattened array to the indexes of an array of a given shape.

```
>> a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,3,1]])
>> np.unravel_index(a.argsort(axis=None), dims=a.shape)
   (array([0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], dtype=int64),
    array([0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0], dtype=int64))
```

The result of `unravel_index` is a tuple of arrays, where each array is the indexes along each respective axis. To pair the indices into coordinates, we can use `zip`:

```
>> ix = np.unravel_index(a.argsort(axis=None), dims=a.shape)
>> zip(*ix)[-3:]
   [(0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 0)]
```

This is, again, in ascending order. We can use a negative stride to get this in descending order.

```
>> zip(*ix)[:2:-1]
   [(1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 2)]
```

Here's the whole thing on one line, where `n` is the number of "top" coordinates you want.

```
>> zip(*np.unravel_index(a.argsort(axis=None), dims=a.shape))[::-1][:n]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to flat your array first , then sort it and use `unique`  to refuse from duplicated entry .

```
>>> a.flatten()
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1])
>>> b=a.flatten()
>>> np.unique(np.sort(b))[-3:]
array([2, 3, 4])
```

and for get the indices you can use `argsort` :

```
>>> b.argsort()[-3:]
array([2, 4, 3])
```

Comment: That will get me the values, but how do I get the indices of those values then?